# how to give different command to buttons created in a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create multiple buttons on a loop,
something like:

```
def press_button(button):
    button.configure(bg="red")


root = tkinter.Tk()

for i in range(4):
    quick_button = tkinter.Button(root, text=str(i) ,font=("courier", 30), 
                                  command=lambda: press_button(quick_button))
    quick_button.grid(row=i, pady=3, padx=3)

root.mainloop()
```

but I want each button to send different argument, what I want is that each button will send different argument, but what happened is that they all set to the same thing, so when I press the first button, the three buttons are being colored.
Also, is there a way to reference buttons without putting them in a dictionary when creating them?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas don't immediately bind the values they use. They are closures and look up the values needed when invoked. What this means is that it will only act on the *last* `quick_button` since that is what `quick_button` equals after your loop is finished. On top of that, you are trying to reference `quick_button` before it exists!

What if I told you that you could exploit this *late binding* behavior which is causing your problem to actually help *solve* your problem?

We can store a list of your buttons (`buttons`) and store the index of the button as a local variable within your lambda. You will then use that index to access the button that was pressed and pass that to your `press_button` function.

It would look something like this:

```py
import tkinter

def press_button(button):
    button.configure(bg="red")


root = tkinter.Tk()

buttons = [] # <-- Added list of buttons
for i in range(4):
    quick_button = tkinter.Button(root, text=str(i) ,font=("courier", 30), 
                                  command=lambda i=i: press_button(buttons[i]))
    quick_button.grid(row=i, pady=3, padx=3)
    buttons.append(quick_button)

root.mainloop()
```

Notice the `lambda i=i` part. Without the `i=i`, you would experience the same behavior as you are experiencing now... When the lambda is called, it will look up the value of `i` and see that it's `3` no matter what button you press. Adding the `i=i` to the lambda binds it locally *within* the lambda.

Now, each button behaves "independently" from the rest:

[image: red buttons]